# Data from an external form (hosted on wordpress site) into sharepoint list

Tags: form

What are my options for getting data from a form hosted on our wordpress site into a sharepoint list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest way would be to setup Incoming Email in SharePoint, and then send you data by email. Don't forget to add captcha field to you wordpress-based form in order to filter out the inevitable spam.

- [Configure incoming email for a SharePoint 2013 farm](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262947(v=office.15).aspx) (Technet, official guide)
- [Configuring SharePoint 2010 to accept incoming emails](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/125119/Configuring-Sharepoint-to-Accept-Incoming-Ema) (CodeProject, unofficial, but with screenshots)

Another option would be, for example, a custom web service, that would receive the data and put it into the list using CSOM.

Answer (score 4):

Another option would be to consume [SharePoint REST service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj860569(v=office.15).aspx) for that purpose using JavaScript or [PHP](http://php.net/) in WordPress site

If [PHP](http://php.net/) is allowed in your WordPress site, then you could utilize [SharePoint client for PHP](https://github.com/vgrem/phpSPO)  that allows to performs CRUD operations on SharePoint data using an SharePoint 2013 REST/OData based API.

### Scenario

Assume a custom Contacts form developed in WordPress site. And it is required to save contacts info in SharePoint Online `Contacts` list during form submit.

Then the following code snippet demonstrates how to save contacts info on form submit:

```
if ($_POST['submitted']) {
    saveContact();
} 

function saveContact(){

    $url = "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/";
    $username = "username@tcontoso@microsoft.com";
    $password = "password" 
    $client = new SPOClient($url);
    $client->signIn($username,$password);

    $list = $client->getList('Contacts');
    $contactEntry = buildContactEntry();    //collect properties from form  
    $item = $list->addItem($contactEntry);
    print "Contact '{$item->Title}' has been created successfully.\r\n";
}
```

### References

- [SharePoint Online client for PHP](http://blog.vgrem.com/2014/05/31/sharepoint-online-client-php/)

Comment: +1! Thanks for sharing, very interesting library! I think this solution is definitely "the way to go" for SPO, since SPO doesn't support Incoming Emails anyways; while Incoming Emails will be the right approach for on-premise SharePoint.

Comment: Actually you can send messages to SharePoint using third party tools like Workflow Actions Pack (https://plumsail.com/workflow-actions-pack/docs/). Review this article for details https://plumsail.com/blog/2013/12/how-to-create-helpdesk-on-sharepoint-2013online/. I'm developer of this product.