# POST Data to SharePoint Online from Formidable Forms (WordPress) using GitHub

Tags: sharepoint-online

I need to POST data from a Formidable Form (WordPress) to a SharePoint Online list. I am simulating the code you added above but I have never used GitHub and I am new to PHP. How do I link to the GitHub script above as I would with JQuery? Do I need to actually download the zip file and add it to the WordPress site or can I just reference the URL? If referencing the URL, what is the syntax for it in PHP?

Comment: Which code (added above) are you talking about?

Comment: More info, which script?

Comment: I am sorry, the script is posted at the following: 
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/85227/data-from-an-external-form-hosted-on-wordpress-site-into-sharepoint-list